# How can I map these entities using hibernate? Need to map one to many relationship. Foreign key is not updating

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, thymeleaf

In this case, I have 2 entities (Users table and UploadRecord table). I need to map a one-to-many relationship because one user can have many upload records. I need to use UserId as the primary key in the Users table and a foreign key as the UploadRecord table.

I tried using this code but the UploadRecord table fk_UserId is not updating. How to fix this issue?

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_UserId", referencedColumnName = "UserId")
    private List<UploadRecord> uploadRecord;
```

I wrote Users entity class and UploadRecord entity class as follows.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name= "UserId")
    private Long UserId;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 45)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "fullName", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String fullName;



    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_UserId", referencedColumnName = "UserId")
    private List<UploadRecord> uploadRecord;

//Getters and setters
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "uploadrecord")
public class UploadRecord {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long uploadRecordId;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = false, length = 1000)
    private String fileName;

//Getters and setters
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't finished modelling the relationship between these two entities.

Edit your models like this:

User:

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<UploadRecord> uploadRecords;
```

UploadRecord :

```java
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
private User user;
```

More details for modelling relations: [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships)

Moreover keep an eye on naming convention:

- UserId -> userId
- uploadRecord -> uploadRecords (Lists, Sets, ...) -> plural